# Fragment menu's not changing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

i'm trying to figure out why the menu is not changing in the actionbar when switching between fragments in my main activity. I've tried some of the suggestions about setHasOptionsMenu(true) and menu.clear and no luck... I just don't get it.

ConsoleActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
  final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
  actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
  actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

  // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
  actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(

  // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
  new ArrayAdapter<String>(actionBar.getThemedContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
    getString(R.string.NavItem1),
    getString(R.string.NavItem2) }), this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
  // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
  // container view.
  Fragment fragment = new SectionFragment();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putInt(SectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
  fragment.setArguments(args);
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
  return true;
}


public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment {
/**
* The fragment argument representing the section number for this
* fragment.
*/
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

public SectionFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
  // number argument value.
  View mView = null;
  switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
  case 1:
    mView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_fragment, container, false);
    break;
  case 2:
    mView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.timesheet_fragment, container, false);
    break;
  }         
  return mView;
}
```

ScheduleFragment.class:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_fragment, null);
  }

  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.schedule_context, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }

}
```

schedule.xml in menu folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_edit_trips"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_trips"
          android:title="Trips"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/menuitem_trip_edit"
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_trip_edit"
                  android:title="Edit" />

            <item android:id="@+id/menuitem_trip_new"
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_trip_new"
                  android:title="New" />

            <item android:id="@+id/menuitem_trip_cancel"
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_trip_cancel"
                  android:title="Cancel" />
        </menu> 
    </item>

</menu>
```

main.xml in menu folder. This is the menu that remains consistent between all the fragments:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menuitem_main"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_main"
          android:title="Main"
          android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menuitem_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_main_logout"
                android:title="Logout" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/menuitem_about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_main_about"
                android:title="About" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/menuitem_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_main_settings"
                android:title="@string/menu_settings" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I'm not sure what to do...

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it, Not sure if this a correct solution but here's what i did:

I added this to my ConsoleActivity.class

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
    switch (sectionNumber) {
    case 1:
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.schedule, menu);
        break;
    case 2:
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.timesheet, menu);
        break;      
    default:
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I added a class variable:

```
private byte sectionNumber = 0;
```

and Finally I added getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); here:

```
public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public SectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
        // number argument value.
        View mView = null;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
        case 1:
            mView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_fragment, container, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            mView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.timesheet_fragment, container, false);
            break;
        }
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return mView;
    }       
}
```

This is my onNavigationItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
    // container view.
    Fragment fragment = new SectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    sectionNumber = (byte) (position + 1);
    args.putInt(SectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: As for me I would prefer to create two separated `Fragment` classes for "Schedule" and "Timesheet" fragments, override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` inside them and add them (or replace if there is already one exists) to the `Activity` depends on `ARG_SECTION_NUMBER`.

Comment: actually that's exactly what i did after i posted this solution i began to understand how to create two fragments and instantiate them without the need of the section fragment inner class inside the activity. Thank you once again